# How to programmatically set the height of a BootstrapTable element?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I need to programmatically set the height of a `BootstrapTable` element (because I want to ensure that the table takes the available space up to the bottom of the browser window). I tried to set the CSS property `height` of the div with the CSS class `react-bs-table` (that's where the height would go if I set it in the `height` attribute of the `BootstrapTable` element). Looks like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   // Calculate the height
   let height = 200; // Only simluated here!

   // Set the height
   const tableElement = document.getElementsByClassName('react-bs-table')[0];
   tableElement.style.height = height + 'px';
}
```

Problem with this approach is that the data rows of the `BootstrapTable` overflow it's bottom border. Seems like the height of this overflow is the height of the header.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freeboarder42/ots4Lawj/3/)

How can I set the height of a `BootstrapTable` correctly (without the data rows overflowing the element)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `maxHeight` prop (*not* `height`) of `<BootstrapTable>` to set the height, rather than modifying the DOM element.

Have a look at the [official docs](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#maxHeight):

> Use [`maxHeight`](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#maxHeight) to set the maximum height of table. You need give a string with an unit(px) value like [`height`](http://allenfang.github.io/react-bootstrap-table/docs.html#height):

Just do the following changes:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let height = 200;
  this.setState({tableHeight: height + "px"});
}

render() {
  ...
  <BootstrapTable maxHeight={this.state.tableHeight} id="table" data={this.state.products} striped hover>
  ...
}
```

You might want to initialize `this.state.tableHeight` in your constructor as well...

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ots4Lawj/4)

---

If you still want to update the styling the way you do it, directly through the DOM and not with React (though discouraged), you can do:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let height = 200;
  const tableElement = document.getElementsByClassName('react-bs-container-body')[0];
  tableElement.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
}
```

Note that I used `react-bs-container-body` and not `react-bs-table`.

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ots4Lawj/5/)

Comment: The React solution works perfectly. I just somehow did not think of binding the height or maxHeight to a state property. Anyway, I used heigth, because I wanted to always have the table reach to the bottom of the page (minus a footer with buttons).

Comment: Excellent! Glad I could help.